# How to generate an eclipse project from a maven pom file for the compilation target only?

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I want to generate an **eclipse project** from a pom file that will **ignore resources** (code and libraries) that are not required for the compilation (like tests resources...)

Oh, and I can't modify the original pom file.

For now now, I use:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:eclipse
```

And I get a project with the test sources and dependencies included.

Is there some parameter or config file that I can pass to that command to exclude the unwanted stuff?

**Update** I don't want to have to use `m2e`or change my eclipse configuration.

Comment: Just import the project into Eclipse as a Maven project (prerequisites the m2e plugin).

Comment: The m2 plugin is something that I want to avoid. Requirement updated.